# Is there a way to run a batch file when opening Visual Studio or a project/solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, batch-file

I use SUBST to map a common drive for referencing some DLLs.  I have been running a batch file in my startup folder to do the mapping, but I'd like to have the drive "gone" when I'm not working in Visual Studio.   Is there a way to automatically run command line instructions when opening/closing Visual Studio and/or when opening a project or solution?

Thanks,
John

Comment: You can do pre- and post-build commands.  Would that be sufficient?

Comment: Could be painful if the drive can't be mapped quickly.

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't be too complicated to take an example extension for visual studio and add your commands - but then its trivial to start visual studio via a batch file or similar:

```
map-drive-command
c:\path\to\devenv.exe
unmap-drive-command
```